# Android Studio 4.2.1 Device Explorer missing again

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Update Android Studio to 4.2.1 version. After that when i make new project 'Flutter Demo', there is no Device Explorer. I tried on win 10 and MacOS 10.15.7 - no matter. What could be the problem?

Comment: i don't know if it works or not.. try adb reconnect

Comment: What do you mean? And i think this problem not rely with adb, because in old projects all ok. i see the differences between them in gradle files...

Answer (score 1):

@Makarenkov Oleg: that worked for me thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DE "aren't surfaced currently but we may be able to add them in the future." (https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4994).
I found such solution: Project Structure/Modules/ add "Android"
[image]